# Why these equalities are making me confused: $\frac{(0,01)^{x-1}}{(0,1)^{3-x}} = 10^{-4x-2}$

Tags: exponential-function

$$\frac{(0,01)^{x-1}}{(0,1)^{3-x}} = 10^{-4x-2}$$

I don't have any idea about where I'm going wrong and why.

$$\frac{(\frac{1}{10^2})^{x-1}}{(\frac{1}{10})^{3-x}} = 10^{-4x-2}$$

$$\frac{(\frac{1}{10^2})^{x-1}}{10^{-3+x}} = 10^{-4x-2}$$

The thing I want to know is If there's any strategy/tips to solve the questions which contain the terms like $x \cdot 10^y$ That's why it makes me confused.

Comment: why are you confused on such a nice saturday evening?

Comment: You can use the exponentaition rule as $10^a\cdot 10^b=10^{a+b}$ and $10^x=10^y\iff x=y$

Comment: @Busi the exponent on the RHS is -4-2 or -4x-2?

Comment: @gimusi $-4x-2$ that's what I forgot writing.

Comment: @Busi Ok I've fixed too, anyway that's doesn't change the way to solve!

Comment: Busi, another exam coming up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is $$\frac{(10^{-2})^{x-1}}{(10^{-1})^{3-x}}=10^{--4x-2}$$ and this is
$$\frac{10^{-2x+2}}{10^{-3+x}}=10^{-4x-2}$$
and you will get $$10^{-2x+2-(x-3)}=10^{-4x-2}$$
so $$-2x+2-(x-3)=-4x-2$$

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follow

$$\frac{(\frac{1}{10^2})^{x-1}}{10^{-3+x}} = 10^{-4x-2}\iff(\frac{1}{10^2})^{x-1} = 10^{-4x-2}{10^{-3+x}}\iff10^{-2x+2}=10^{-3x-5}\\\iff-2x+2=-3x-5\iff x=-7$$

Comment: See the new edit please, I had miswriten $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(0,01)^{x-1}=(10^{-2})^{x-1}=10^{-2 (x-1)}=10^{-2x+2} $$

$$(0,1)^{3-x}=(10^{-1})^{3-x}=10^{-3+x} $$

the quotient will be
$$10^{(-2x+2)-(-3+x)}=10^{5-3x} =10^{-4x-2}$$

thus $$5-3x=-4x-2$$
and $$x=-7$$

Comment: I'm truly sorry, had miswritten $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should have in mind is to convert everything to base $10$. Note that: $$a^{b+c}=a^ba^c$$

$$a^{b-c}=\dfrac{a^b}{a^c}$$
$$(0.1)^a=10^{-a}$$

This should help you.

Hint(s):

> $$0.01=10^{-2}\implies (0.01)^{x-1}=(10^{-2})^{x-1}=10^{-2x+2}$$$$0.1^{3-x}=(10^{-1})^{3-x}=10^{x-3}$$
> Using the second property of exponents I had mentioned: $$\dfrac{10^{-2x+2}}{10^{x-3}}=10^{-2x+2-(x-3)}$$